# while loop is not working the code isn't running 60 frames

Tags: c#

I am trying to work this simple code out I need this code to run for for 5 seconds in a continuous loop without putting it into update.

```
void Update () {

}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("IcePickup"))
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);

        Blade1 = GameObject.Find("Blade1");
        Blade1.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = IceBlade;

        int counting = 1;
        while (counting <= 10)
        {
            print("icey");
            (Blade1.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -0.50f)); 
            counting ++; 
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Blade1.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -0.50f)); woops there should be no bracket on this...

Comment: so the blade is spinning on another script its going 0,0,-3.00f but when i get the ice pickup i am trying to change the speed to -0.50f but i cannot work it out.

Comment: Edit your question to update it with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe this example can help you:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        int Seconds = 5;
        int Counter = 0;

        while(DateTime.Now - StartTime < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Seconds))
        {
            //Your Code here?
            Counter++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("In " + Seconds + "seconds are " + Counter + "iterations");
    }
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question - but your coded loop counts to `10`. 10 iterations, not seconds. Those 10 iterations might take 3 milliseconds or a year or 40 nanoseconds, it depends on how fast that function is.

Chances are that all 10 iterations are done before the first frame is displayed, which might explain your issue.

You cannot simple code a `while` for so many seconds; you need to question the timer device and handle that criteria yourself. Or you try around with larger and larger iteration counts until you find an about number that takes about five seconds.